# Show Child of Parent Page including all other parents

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I'm trying to show on the menus as assigned in WP Menu backend however how is possible to load child of parent page without hiding the rest.

Example

Main-1
Main-2
Main-3

When Clicking on Main-1 should show

Main-1
---Sub-1
---Sub-2
Main-2
Main-3

```
    <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'secondary' )) { 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'         => '', 
    'container_class'   => '', 
    'menu_class'        => '', 
    'menu_id'           => 'menu-header-menu', 
    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_page_menu',
    'items_wrap'        => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'sort_column'       => 'menu_order', 
    'theme_location'    => 'secondary' ) );
}
```

This is the main code I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'depth'=>-1` will show all the levels ([source^](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)):

> **$depth**
> *(integer)* (optional) How many levels of the hierarchy are to be included where `0` means all. `-1` displays links at any depth and arranges them in a single, flat list.
> Default: 0

So your code will be:

```
<?php if (has_nav_menu( 'secondary' )) { 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'         => '', 
    'menu_class'        => '', 
    'menu_id'           => 'menu-header-menu', 
    'items_wrap'        => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'             => -1,
    'theme_location'    => 'secondary' ) );
}
```

And **DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself**. As the default value of `fallback_cb` is `wp_page_menu`, you don't need to repeat it. So do the `container_class`. And there's no such `sort_column` parameter in `wp_nav_menu()`.

#### EDIT

You must put

```
register_nav_menus( array( 'secondary'=>__('Secondary Menu', 'text-domain') ) );
```

in your `functions.php` register the nav menu so that you can assign your menu to this location. Even though you create a new menu from Appearance » Menus, if you not assign it to the desired location, then you can't enable it to there.

Comment: thank you bro for the script but still not working. I want to show both parent and child of the current parent at the same it. Remark I'm using wordpress menu defining location and links. So what I want if I have
- Main1  
- Main2  
- Main3
And clicked on Main 1 that should look like:

- Main 1
--- Sub1
--- Sub2
- Main 2
- Main 3

Then I click on Main 2 it will be
- Main 1
- Main 2    
---Sub1
---Sub2
- Main 3

Comment: You assigned a Nav menu from Appearance > Menus to the Secondary menu location, is that correct? But it's not showing up menus and submenus...etc. I'm not getting you correctly. If you are not assigning any dynamic menu and want an automatic one why not you use [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu)?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I'm assigning the menu from Appearance> Menus to the Secondary menu location. And exactly the problem it's taking the menu as been built in backend and not showing the submenus. I'm not using page menu because I don't wanna show all pages in the menu only selected ones

Comment: have a look at the edit.